# Dynamically change API endpoints and base url based on user input

Tags: reactjs, file, redux, environment-variables, config

I have a Create-React application with a settings page in it, inside this settings page, the user has several inputs (form inputs) inside of which he can define certain parameters like backend server endpoint, API endpoints... so here is the problem, how can I persist this data in this application without the need for an additional backend server for my front-end application, please note that I tried using .env variables but I couldn't manage to update those based on user input, config files didn't work too since the front-end app is only alive inside the browser and can't access the files, I also tried using Local storage, it worked but again, I can't persist that to the whole application (since Local storage is bound to the browser, changing the browser will change the data) , lastly I considered using redux and store the configs in the store and update the state based on button clicks, but I'm not really sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: You want access to that data with different browsers as well? 
Then, you need to have a backend server to store the data. There's no either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically there are several ways to store the client side data in browser; like cookie storage, local Storage, and if you are using redux may be redux with [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) could be a great choice for this type of use case.

but as you mentioned you want to persist that data between user sessions of the application, for example you user can access the application from chrome, firefox, or even from his/her mobile browser, honestly for your situation there is nothing rather than store the required input data in database ( backend folks should do this ) and provide the data to the authenticated user in an api. there is no way rather than that!